# Precedence Constraint in OR-Tools

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, c++

I'm trying to write this constraint in C++ and add it to my model (`addLessOrEqual`):
$$\text{start}_{i}+\text{duration}_{i}\le\text{start}_{j}$$ for an $(i,j)$ arc of precedence.

Starts (`IntVar`) and durations (`int`) are part of an `IntervalVar`. The problem is that I can't operate $+$ with `IntVar` and `Int`.

I'm using C++ and i get this error:

```cpp
    error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are 
‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<operations_research::sat::IntVar> 
>::value_type {aka operations_research::sat::IntVar}’ and 
‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}’)
                 cp_model.AddLessOrEqual(starts[j]+durations[j],starts[succ[j][s]])
```

What can I do to sum and get the expression? Is there another predefined constraint that does the same?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with or-tools but have you tried bringing all of your expression to the left-hand side and your value to the right-hand side and see if the error goes away?

Comment: I did this but now the problem is with the operator.

Comment: `AddLessOrEqual(LinearExpr(starts[j]).AddConstant(durations[j]), starts[succ[j][s]])`

Comment: thanks Stradivari, apparently it works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is:

```
AddLessOrEqual(LinearExpr(starts[j]).AddConstant(durations[j]), starts[succ[j][s]])
```

You might also want to take a look at the examples (ending with `_sat.cc`) to be more familiar with the c++ methods.

https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/master/examples/cpp